# react typescript with function passed as prop, but can't access

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making a simple toggle button with react + typescript.
I want to practice some complex feature by passing function as prop to child component.
I remember 'this.props' allows me to access all props passed to child in typescript. So if I define a function in parent, I should be able to call the function in child, right?

But I got the below error. Can someone please give me a helping hand? Thank you.

Error:

> (property) React.DOMAttributes.onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler | undefined
> Type '(checked: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.
> Types of parameters 'checked' and 'event' are incompatible.
> Type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)

Code:

src/

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Switch from './Switch';

interface State {
  buttonOn: boolean;
}

class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, State> {
  public state: State = {
    buttonOn: false,
  };

  onChange = (checked: boolean) => this.setState({ buttonOn: checked });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch
          checked={this.state.buttonOn}
          onChange={(checked) => this.onChange(!checked)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app')!);
```

src/Switch/

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';

interface Props {
  checked: boolean;
  onChange: (checked: boolean) => void;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export default class Switch extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.props.onChange} /> {/* error here */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is - you _can_ access it, but the function you're passing as a prop is not a match for the onClick callback of an element because the parameter types don't match. Note just making a div clickable is not a good idea from an accessibility perspective.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your attention. May I ask a bit more? If onClick isn't a good practice, then what should i use?

Answer (score 1):

so you have 2 options... Either

1. Do it like this where `this.props.onChange` is being returned by the `onClick` lambda function. You can also wrap this in curly braces if you want

```
export default class Switch extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={(e) => this.props.onChange} /> {/* error here */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

or;

2. Change your types... It's always worth hovering over a property such as `onClick` to understand the function signature as well as the type of arguments that are being passed in.

```js
# src/App.tsx
import React from "react";
import Switch from "./Switch";

interface State {
  buttonOn: boolean;
}

class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, State> {
  public state: State = {
    buttonOn: false
  };

  onChange = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    console.log(event);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch checked={this.state.buttonOn} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then in the Switch:

```js
# src/Switch.tsx

import React from "react";

interface Props {
  checked: boolean;
  onChange: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export default class Switch extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onChange}> Hello world </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I wrote a [Codesandbox playground here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-tharp-5eqd8k?file=/src/Switch.tsx:0-367) so you can test it out yourself.